# Having trouble passing PFUser as a PFObject

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

so in my app, I want to implement user profiles by clicking on a `UIButton`, I have all the functionality done.

I first added the functionality when the `indexPath.section` is selected the user information is shown, so then I wanted to do the same thing through a button.

heres my code in `-(void)didSelectRow`

```
PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
PFUser *user = [object objectForKey:@"userTookPhoto"];

self.userInfo = user;
```

self.userInfo is a property `PFUser` in the `.h` file

Then in my `PrepareSegue` I have this :

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"homeToProfile2"])
    {

        transfer.userInformationObject = self.userInfo;
    }
```

I run the app, and i tap on the button to push segue and the app crashes saying that `self.userInfo` is NULL.

When I `NSlog` it in `didSelectRow`, it has the information correct with all the user details,
when I `NSlog` it in the `prepareSegue` it crashes as it says it is `NULL`.

Comment: Parse executes on queries. Your going to have to make a query to find the current user that matches the title of the string in the cell or whatever way you have your backend set up I don't know cause I can't see it.  It's returning nil because technically it is nil. You are essentially trying to create a user but return it in self.userinfo instead you should query the user and return in self.userinfo

Comment: Are you sure your object is actually there and not nil to begin with? If it is, have you used includeKey: "userTookPhoto" on the query to include the user while fetching the query results?

Comment: Just wondering... Did my post help at all ?

Comment: @jsetting32 yeah it did sorry i didnt check ur answer correct.
I was also wondering how you could implement a like button in parse ios.

Comment: Its a pretty hefty amount of coding but its very good to learn how to implement the like button. Head over to Parse.com and download the `Anypic` iOS application. They have the implementation that you need. Review the classes `PAPUtility`, `PAPCache` and `PAPPhotoTimelineViewController`. I also have an application I developed `crossbook` (iPhone app not iPad) thats in the App Store if you want to see it in action on a production application other than Anypic. Also, gimme a holler if you need help with getting a better understanding with some of the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `PFObjects` objects within a `PFObject`, you need to include within your PFQuery the `includeKey:` method and pass in the field that the `PFObject` is...

So if your accessing a `PFUser` object within a `PFObject` whose classname is 'Message', you create the query like so...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassname:@"Message"];
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query includeKey:@"toUser"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [obj objectForKey:@"toUser"]);
    }
}];
```

The log statement will return the PFUser object.

Heres a link to an explanation of your problem on [Parse Blog](http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/06/queries-for-relational-data/)