# Parse.com iOS PFQuery for Class with Pointer

Tags: parse-platform

Im trying to implement a search bar using PFQueryTableView.

I can successfully retrieve objects that are inside a class with no pointer column with this code:

---

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query;

if (self.canSearch == 0) {
    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
} else {
    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    NSString *searchThis = [searchedBar.text lowercaseString];
    #warning key you wanted to search here
    [query whereKey:@"colors" containsString:searchThis];
}

[query orderByAscending:@"colors"];
```

But when I use this same query to search objects in a column that is in the same Class that have another column Pointer<_User> the query doesn't work anymore.

What should I change in the code above to query that column(with no Pointer) that exists inside a Class with a pointer column ?

Thanx and cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my answer here : [Having trouble passing PFUser as a PFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351961/having-trouble-passing-pfuser-as-a-pfobject/27397677#27397677)

I think this is what your looking for. It involves accessing `PFObjects` within `PFObjects`

Comment: Hi thanx for the reply. In my case I am not accessing directly the PFUser, but a column in a class that have a Pointer<_User>. The main issue in my case was PFACL settings. Depending the way they are configured it can restrict queries even to columns that are not the pointers itself. I think Parse should provide more examples of these type of queries that deal with some PFACL settings.